# ¿Cómo contar intentos de inicio de sesión? (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

He utilizado el comando `php artisan make:auth` para que Laravel me cree un inicio/registro de sesión de manera automática. Quiero que el inicio de sesión sea similar a un banco, me refiero a que le diga al usuario cuantos intentos le quedan disponibles para poder entrar.

Hasta los momentos le he agregado 2 variables al controlador LoginController la primera de ellas es: `public $maxAttempts = 3;` que me limita la cantidad de veces que un usuario puede intentar iniciar sesión.

Y la segunda `public $decayMinutes = 60` que es el tiempo que se bloqueara a ese usuario luego de haber bloqueado su usuario si supera los intentos.

El controlador **LoginController.php** entonces me ha quedado de esta manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesUsers;

public $maxAttempts = 10;
public $decayMinutes = 60

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero ahora es hacerle saber al usuario cuantos intentos le quedan disponible, es decir si la cantidad de intentos es de 3 y el usuario falla en su primer intento de acceder, le diga la cantidad de intentos restantes que le quedan antes de bloquear su usuario.

Answer (score -1):

Agrega Esta funcion a tu LoginController;

```
public function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{   


    $attempts = session()->get('login.attempts', 0); // obtener intentos, default: 0
    if ($attempts<=2) {
    session()->put('login.attempts', $attempts + 1); // incrementrar intentos
    return redirect()->back()->with('status','intento :'.$attempts);
        }
```

Comment: Que tal NineLTS, bienvenido... Puedes detallar tu respuesta?? si bien los fragmentos de código son esenciales, seria mucho mejor si dieras alguna explicación sobre el porqué esa seria la solución, o como es que ese fragmento de codigo puede ayudarlo... date una vuelta por [answer] para mas información